# Is it correct to post whole of the code in question?

Tags: discussion, code

### How I Came Up with this Question?

Is it a good way to post the whole code, the whole project in a question? I see new users or even many old ones posting the whole code and ask to point out where the error is or what needs to be added or deleted from the code.

It is just in every one-tenth of questions that whole project is not posted. This isn't easy to read or understand. The person's mind just gets blown.

The user should post fair amount of code. I know posting code is a must for us to know where the error is but pointing out where the error is makes it easy and understandable. I have noticed questions (easy or tough) with lesser code get more attention and more answers and votes.

It also doesn't look safe posting whole of the code. It has chances of being stolen.

### My Doubt

- Should we **post the whole code** instead of some part which has to do something with the question?
- Is it **safe** posting whole of the code?

Comment: You shouldn't post either the whole project or a snippet of the project; you should post a simplified complete program that replicates the issue and nothing else

Comment: @RichardTingle I agree with you and the doubt is cleared. Hah! But who would tell the users who do this? They see the `how to ask` page just as `terms and conditions`.

Comment: Shouldn't this be on SO meta, not main meta?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Safe" really depends on the situation. If this is code that you have written as part of your job then you need to discuss with your employer whether you are allowed to post the code. In any case, passwords and unique tokens used for security or authentication (or any other sensitive information) should always be replaced with placeholders.

An entire project should *never* be posted in a question. Code provided in a post should be the minimal amount needed to recreate the problem.

This issue is mentioned in the Help Center under the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section:

> #### Help others reproduce the problem
>
> Not all questions benefit from including code. But if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some. But **don't just copy in your entire program!** Not
> only is this likely to get you in trouble if you're posting your
> employer's code, it likely includes a lot of irrelevant details that
> readers will need to ignore when trying to reproduce the problem. Here
> are some guidelines:
>
> - Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For
>   help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Valid Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
> - If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can
>   link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/)
>   then do so - but also include the code in your question itself. Not
>   everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.

<sub>That bold text is not mine - this is how it actually appears in the Help center.</sub>

Comment: I agree with you and the doubt is cleared. Hah! But who would tell the users who do this? They see the how to ask page just as terms and conditions.

Comment: @KashishArora - the fact that users don't read what is right in front of them is a different issue :P The only people who can really make sure all users know this are people like you and me. People who know what needs to be done and why. It's our job as more experienced [so] users to help educate newer users and nudge them in the right direction.